# I want to select data from last 3 days partition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL, It is possible to get data from 3 days partitions only. For example, If I run SQL on 15-Aug-2019, My SQL should only look on 13,14,15 Day partitions or If I run SQL on 16-Aug-2019, My SQL should only look on 14,15,16 Day partitions.

TIA

Comment: How are the partitions defined? Normally though, you would just use a `date` condition as normal and let the database figure out which partitions to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are just looking for the following `where` clause:

```
where my_date_col >= trunc(sysdate) - 2 and my_date_col < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

Where `date_col` is the column that holds the `date` that you want to filter.

For current sysdate December 30th at 10h22, `trunc(sysdate)` gives you December 30th at midnight, and  `trunc(sysdate) - 2` produces December 28th at midnight.

Comment: No, I Specifically want to mention partition number in the select statement.

Comment: @SagarChawla: why? Your database can efficiently determine which partitions should be used based on the date criteria that you pass in your query.

Comment: Well, My table size is more than 120 GB and its growing daily and there are 30 columns. My SQL is going into full table scan.  I am writing a report wherein only need data which got inserted or modified in the last 2 hours.

Comment: I thought of writing a function which can give the names of the last 3 days partition. It is possible to call function name in the partition clause. For example select * from TAB_A partition (Part1(),Part2());

Comment: @SagarChawla: If you are using the same date column for partitioning and as a filter condition in the `where` clause, no full scan will happen. Oracle will pick the relevant partitions to select from and not query over all partitions. You can try it by yourself (just generate the explain plan of a query that filters on the date column).